# ¿Como hacer un formulario que de como resultado un código listo para copiar y pegar?

Tags: php, html

Hola amigos tengo un problema, no es muy complejo pero no entiendo cómo podría hacerlo.

Deseo hacer un formulario en HTML que pida 3 valores los cuales serían:

URL 1, URL 2 y URL 3

Con un botón que diga "Generar", cuando se haga esto en pantalla se muestre un código que tenga una estructura como está pero usando los valores ingresados en el formulario, básicamente para que solo sea copiar y pegar en la aplicación final la.cual es un paste.

```
[center][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img]
 [url=URL 1 EN ESTE LUGAR]Enlace VIP[/url] |

[center][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img]
 [url=URL 2 EN ESTE LUGAR]Enlace VIP[/url] |
 [img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=uptobox.com[/img]
 [url=URL 2 EN ESTE LUGAR[/url][/center]
```

Básicamente como pueden ver el formulario lo que haría sería reemplazar en el minicodigo las URLS en los Lugares donde dice "URL X EN ESTE LUGAR" y dar como texto el código ya con las URLS solo para que se copié y pegue en el paste deseado.

Se que se puede hacer con PHP quizá con la función `<?php print() ?>` O algo así pero como soy nuevo en esto no sé cómo podría hacerlo encajar.

De antemano agradezco a todos su enorme ayuda y pasen un excelente día.

Comment: ¿Estás usando WordPress? Por favor danos más datos sobre tu código

Comment: No, lo que quiero hacer es un script que haga eso en php no tengo claro como hacer eso

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el formulario que vas a usar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que estas usando php, creo que podría servirte este código.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['url1'])&&
    isset($_POST['url2'])&&
    isset($_POST['url3'])
    )
{
    echo "Resultado:". "<br>";

    $line   ='[center][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img][url='.$_POST['url1'].']Enlace VIP[/url][/center]'  . "<br>";

    $line  .='[center][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=google.com/drive[/img][url='.$_POST['url2'].']Enlace VIP[/url][/center]' ."<br>";

    $line  .='[center][img]https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=uptobox.com[/img][url='.$_POST['url2'].'][/url][/center]' . "<br>";

    echo $line;
}
else
{
?>

    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="url1">URL 1</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" value=""><br>
        <label for="url2">URL 2</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="url2" id="url2"><br>
        <label for="url3">URL 3</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="url3" id="url3"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Generar">
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Ya dirás si se acerca a la solución que buscas.

Saludos.